# Keep the applied modifications in node_modules files

Tags: angular, ionic4, node-modules, git-fork

To fix some errors I have to modify some files under node_modules, I know its not a good approach to change in node_modules files, but there was no solution rather than this. 
Now I am facing an issue, every time I reinstall node_modules I have to rewrite changes to node_modules files. On Google I have found forking a repo could be a solution but I couldn't apply that either. Please tell what solution should I apply.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why cant you fork it?

Comment: you're gona have to fork it or lift it out of node modules and put it in your src directory and modify your imports or write a mapping in tsconfig

Comment: @alphapilgrim Actually I tried forking it, but unable to do it successfully, now I'm gonna try it again. If you know any good link to follow on forking github repo then please share. Thanks